# SharePoint workflows testing environment

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, testing

Is there any way, how I can set up a proper testing environment for workflows in SharePoint 2013 (created in SharePoint Designer)? And I mean real testing environment that I can easily deploy to a production once finalized. Not copying one item after another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create sharepoint farm using production copy and do your workflow testing. this is the real testing environment as Content DB is copy of production.

Let me know if you need more information

Comment: So if I am just an owner of one of the sites with no admin privileges/skills needed for creating an extra SharePoint farm, I can't do that? Are there any debugging options for regular users?

Comment: yes you can test but you need to get a farm with contribute access. This can not be done with read access.